# Efficient way to iterate and copy the values of HashMap

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream

I want to convert:

```
Map<String, Map<String, List<Map<String, String>>>> inputMap
```

to:

```
Map<String, Map<String, CustomObject>> customMap
```

`inputMap` is provided in the config and is ready but I need to `customMap` Format. CustomObject will be derived from `List<Map<String, String>>` using few lines of code in a function.

I have tried a normal way of iterating input map and copying key values in customMap. Is there any efficient way of doing that using Java 8 or some other shortcut?

```
Map<String, Map<String, List<Map<String, String>>>> configuredMap = new HashMap<>();
Map<String, Map<String, CustomObj>> finalMap = new HashMap<>();


for (Map.Entry<String, Map<String, List<Map<String, String>>>> attributeEntry : configuredMap.entrySet()) {
    Map<String, CustomObj> innerMap = new HashMap<>();
    for (Map.Entry<String, List<Map<String, String>>> valueEntry : attributeEntry.getValue().entrySet()) {
        innerMap.put(valueEntry.getKey(), getCustomeObj(valueEntry.getValue()));
    }
    finalMap.put(attributeEntry.getKey(), innerMap);
}

private CustomObj getCustomeObj(List<Map<String, String>> list) {
    return new CustomObj();
}
```

Comment: Please format the code properly.

Comment: Have you thought about creating a facade, rather than copying?

Comment: There can't be any more efficient way. All those operations have to take place. But this code doesn't actually work. You're not putting the list into the custom object.

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to stream the `entrySet` of `inputMap`, and then use [`Collectors#toMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap(java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.Function)) twice (once for the outer `Map`, and once for the inner `Map`):

```
Map<String, Map<String, CustomObj>> customMap = inputMap.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), entry -> {
            return entry.getValue()
                        .entrySet()
                        .stream()
                        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), 
                            entry -> getCustomeObj(entry.getValue())));
        }));
```

Comment: You can omit the `{}` and the return statement in the lambda, something like this: `.collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), entry -> 
            entry.getValue()
                        .entrySet()
                        .stream()
                        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), 
                            entry -> getCustomeObj(entry.getValue())));
        ));`

Comment: @SHoko True, but I think it would look less readable without the block.

Answer (score 1):

You could stream, but that ain't going to look readable; at least to me.  So if you have a method:

```
static CustomObject fun(List<Map<String, String>> in) {
    return .... // whatever processing you have here
}
```

you could still use the `java-8` syntax, but in a different form:

```
    Map<String, Map<String, CustomObject>> customMap = new HashMap<>();

    inputMap.forEach((key, value) -> {

        value.forEach((innerKey, listOfMaps) -> {

            Map<String, CustomObject> innerMap = new HashMap<>();
            innerMap.put(innerKey, fun(listOfMaps));
            customMap.put(key, innerMap);

        });
    });
```

If you can make the inner map `immutable`, you could make that even shorter:

```
inputMap.forEach((key, value) -> {
      value.forEach((innerKey, listOfMaps) -> {
          customMap.put(key, Collections.singletonMap(innerKey, fun(listOfMaps)));
      });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

IMHO streaming is not so bad idea. There're no bad tools. It depends on how you're using them.

---

In this particular case I would extract the repeating pattern into an utility method:

```
public static <K, V1, V2> Map<K, V2> transformValues(Map<K, V1> map, Function<V1, V2> transformer) {
    return map.entrySet()
              .stream()
              .collect(toMap(Entry::getKey, e -> transformer.apply(e.getValue())));
}
```

The method above can be implemented using any approach, though I think `Stream API` fits pretty well here.

---

Once you defined the utility method, it can be used as simple as follows:

```
Map<String, Map<String, CustomObj>> customMap = 
    transformValues(inputMap, attr -> transformValues(attr, this::getCustomObj));
```

The actual transformation is effectively one liner. So with proper `JavaDoc` for `transformValues` method the result code is pretty readable and maintainable.

Answer (score 1):

How about `Collectors.toMap` for the entries both at an outer and inner level such as:

```
Map<String, Map<String, CustomObj>> finalMap = configuredMap.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,
                attributeEntry -> attributeEntry.getValue().entrySet()
                        .stream()
                        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,
                                valueEntry -> getCustomeObj(valueEntry.getValue())))));
```